# Can't launch lldb on windows, showing "Fatal Python error"

Tags: python, llvm, lldb

Can't launch lldb on windows.
Python already installed and added to path

Python version: 3.10.5

LLVM version: 14.0.0

Windows version: Windows 11 22H2

Outputs:

```
PS C:\Users\26354> lldb
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:/Users/hwennborg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\lldb.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:/Users/hwennborg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:/Users/hwennborg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\lldb.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:/Users/hwennborg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:/Users/hwennborg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\26354\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
    'C:/Users/hwennborg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310\\DLLs',
    'C:/Users/hwennborg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310\\lib',
    'C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000066f4 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Comment: *encodings* is a standard Python module, part of the regular Python installatioion. Maybe your Python is broken, try reinstalling it.